# Angular 2:Google Maps and Angular Google Places

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, api-key

I´m using two components  in the same page,https://angular-maps.com and angular2-google-map-auto-complete. https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-google-map-auto-complete. I define the angular maps key on this way:

```
AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
 apiKey: 'API_KEY'
})
```

And for google map automplete on index file:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&libraries=places"></script>
```

The problem is when I use that components on the same page throws error

```
You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.
```

I know what is the problem but, hoy define single API_KEY to avoid  errors

Answer (score 0):

just remove the

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&libraries=places"></script>
```

from your index.html and add your api key inside the amgCoreModule declaration.